# How to access saved entity via metadata using parameters in the route

Tags: twig, entity, symfony4

I have an entity contact

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ContactRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ContactRepository::class)
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dob;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $email;

    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15)
     */
    private $phone;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDob(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dob;
    }

    public function setDob(?\DateTimeInterface $dob): self
    {
        $this->dob = $dob;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I want to select one (or more) contact with this URL: `/c00210/readallbyparam/{routeProperty}/{routeValue}`

For example: `/c00210/readallbyparam/lastname/Mendelsohn`
This should return 2 records:

- Felix Mendelsohn
- Fanny Mendelsohn

How do I write the render() function?
How do I write the twig instructions?

I suppose I should use the metadata, but I don't know

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

here is the function in my controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/c00210/readallbyparam/{routeProperty}/{routeValue}", name="c00210_read_all_by_param")
 */

public function findAllByparam( $routeProperty,$routeValue)
{

    $property = $routeProperty;
    $value = $routeValue;
    

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Contact::class);
    $contacts = $repository->findAll();

    return $this->render('c00210/readbycriteria2.html.twig', [
        'function' => 'find(<id>)',
        'description' => 'finds the with the given Id',
        'property' => $property,
        'value' => $value,
        'contacts' => $contacts,
    ]);
```

routeProperty should be a column name, and routeValue a column value

shoud be equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE lastname = 'Mendelsohn'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can we see your controller?

Comment: Here is the function in my controller

Comment: Pass your search parameters to the repository `$repository->findBy([$routeProperty => $routeValue])`. But you should consider filtering the allowed properties to not expose sensitive information.